# 1980s Science Fiction book with a manta-shaped ship, people who turn into animals and wind

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I took out a book from the bookmobile in (1989?), and have never been able to track it down again. Memorable because it was one of the first adult sci-fi books I read, and I've been trying to track it down off and on for 15 years.

**Plot details**

It was a sci-fi novel where people had three forms: human, animal, and wind. They could stay in the wind form forever, but had a limited amount of time in the others.

There was an advanced spaceship that looks like a manta-ray or a sting ray. I think that the ship could cloak?

It was an adult book, with enough sex scenes that they probably shouldn't have let me take it out of the library.

**Book Appearance Details**

I remember it having a photo of the ship on the cover, and being around 300pages in length.

That's all that I can remember, any help would be appreciated.

**Books it is not**

- Walls of the World - James Tiptree Jr.
- Any of the Timothy Zahn "Manta" series
- Of Man and Manta - Piers Anthony

**Investigating**

- Wind Dancers - RM Meluch (I don't think this is correct, but some plot points are similar. I've purchased this (and the sequel) to confirm.

Comment: This sounds vaguely like Up the Walls of the World by James Tiptree, Jr. I will double-check and see how closely the plot points match.

Comment: Never mind about Up the Walls of the World. The only thing that matches is there is wind, and there are manta-ray-shaped aliens. The wind isn't alive, there is no spaceship, and although there is astral projection and body-switching, nobody is actually changing forms from wind to human to animal.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a long time since I read this, I don't recall the description of the spaceship at all, but intelligent winds that can shape themselves into animal and human forms makes me think of [*Wind Dancers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5425) (1981) by R.M. Meluch.

The [blurb](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1752869.Wind_Dancers) reads:

> The Morts were turning up all over Aeolis, the Eden-like planet named for the unexpectedwinds which sprang up from nowhere and swiftly faded away. But unlike the winds, the Morts didn't just fade away. These unidentifiable corpses - which on closer examination proved far from human - posed a bizarre threat to human control of Aeolis. So the Serviceship Halcyon XLV was dispatched to the planet to solve the secret of the Morts, a secret whispered by the winds every day - a secret older than mankind, which could spell the end of human life on the planet...

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't think this is it, but it was long enough ago that I've ordered it to see if the rest of the plot fits what I remember.